# Docker for Windows, container started from console is not reachable

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I'm starting to use docker on windows 10 home.

`Docker-engine: 19.03.13`

`Docker-desktop: 2.4.0.0 (48506)`

I've installed the latest version and everything works fine when I'm using the Windows Docker App to start the container. But when I start the container from my console (PowerShell, git-bash, cmd in admin mode) I can't reach this container.

git-bash

`docker run -p 9990:9990 -d --name kc_console jboss/keycloak:latest`

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
e5197e5acd96        jboss/keycloak:latest   "/opt/jboss/tools/doÔÇª"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9980->8080/tcp             kc_app
9607511f2dd8        jboss/keycloak:latest   "/opt/jboss/tools/doÔÇª"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        8080/tcp, 8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9990->9990/tcp   kc_console
```

kc_app container is reachable over the browser but pc_console isn't.

`http://localhost:9980/auth/` works but
`http://localhost:9990/auth/` doesn't work

The only difference I see is the port settings.

In Docker desktop (inspect container):

`pc_console (port: localhost:9990)`

`pc_app (port: 0.0.0.0:9980)`

Anybody knows, how can I fix this?
Environment problem?
Missing settings?

Answer (score 0):

After trying hours and asking her I found the mistake.

I used the parameter -p wrong.

```
docker run -p 9990:8080 -d --name kc_console jboss/keycloak:latest
```

now it works as ecpected.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using `Docker Toolbox` then any port you publish with `docker run -p` will be published on the Docker Toolbox VM’s private IP address.

`docker-machine ip` will tell you. It is generally `192.168.99.100`.

Then you can browse (`192.168.99.100:8080`) instead of (`localhost:8080`).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I'm using docker Desktop. Docker Toolbox is an older version I think.